# Call to undefined function diffInDaysFromToday()

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I use diffInDaysFromToday() in blade but get this error.

Here's my if statement:

```php
@if($course['createdAt'] != null)
  @if( diffInDaysFromToday($course['createdAt']) < 30 )
     <span>{{__('new')}}</span>
  @endif
@endif
```

examlple of course['cretedAt']:

[image]

Where is the problem? Format or something else?

Comment: Where did you define `diffInDaysFromToday` function? In helpers?

Comment: @devcrazy yes, and I wrote the function name incorrectly in helpers. thanks

Comment: Is the helpers file autoloaded properly? Did you try `composer dumpautoload` and check again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($course['createdAt'])->diffInDays() < 30 )
  <span>{{__('new')}}</span>
@endif
```